# Is it possible to reboot a Colab ubuntu machine? And re-SSH to it with the same ngrok credential?

Tags: ssh, google-colaboratory, ssh-tunnel

I am a rookie of SSH. In Google Colaboratory, I want to downgrade Cuda toolkits from 10.1 to 10.0 so that I can use a specific version (2.0) of Tensorflow. After purging old Cuda and reinstalling the correct one, I was told to reboot the remote machine.

Here comes the question: I knew how to SSH to a Colab machine but don't know how to reboot it. Is it possible?

If it's possible to reboot, then can I ssh to the same machine using the same credential created by ngrok?

Does anyone have an idea to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
import os
os._exit(0)
```

It will restart.

Comment: I followed your script and run it in the terminal of the virtual desktop as well as in Colab notebook. I created a regular user to ssh to the remote server. The SSH connection is still alive even though I executed the script you provided to restart the remote machine. As it stands, the server restart is not possible. Thank you though.